# How to copy between Subversion repositories preserving properties but not preserving history

Tags: svn, migrate, svnadmin

How can I copy a folder from one existing Subversion repository to another **without preserving history**, and in such a way that **preserves relevant svn properties** (e.g. preserve `svn:ignore`, `svn:eol-style` but ignore `svn:mergeinfo`).

To use `svn export` followed by `svn import` would not preserve svn properties, so this is not good.

We are currently experimenting with:

> `svnadmin dump /path/to/repo1 -r HEAD | svndumpfilter include project/to/keep | svnadmin load /path/to/repo2`

But so far we have not been able to get the `svnadmin load` to succeed with just these partial dumps.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a simple problem.  We had to create `/projec/to`, but not the `keep` folders on the destination repository prior to reloading.