# How to replace svn:externals with the actual data? I.e. copy from other repository preserving properties

Tags: svn

I have a project managed with Subversion.  That project uses svn:externals to link to other repositories.  Now I want to replace the externals with the actual data they refer to.  How can I do that?  I would need to copy between two repositories, but that is not supported by the command line client.  I also want to preserve the properties like svn:mime-type.  To `add` or `import` the data would use my auto-props or none, but I need the original properties.  I do not have server access.

The best solution I could come up with is `svn merge -r 0:123 http://repo.svn/path/to/external external`, but that doesn't copy the very first version of the external resource and all I get is tree conflicts.

This question is similar to [How to copy between Subversion repositories preserving properties but not preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649143/how-to-copy-between-subversion-repositories-preserving-properties-but-not-preser), but I cannot use `svnadmin load`.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to do that without svnadmin load.

Comment: The best you could do in your situation is delete the `.svn` folders of each external, then `svn add` and `svn commit`them

Comment: @SameerSingh: But what about the properties?  They are lost with a simple add+commit.

Comment: Yes that would be the case unfortunately. Unless you have very special properties which you have set yourself, you can use TortoiseSVN to add auto-properties like `svn:mimetype` when performing the add

Comment: Sure, I can add new properties.  But what I try to achieve is to preserve the original properties.  I could query the external repo for the properties and apply them to the added data, but that requires at least a script that walks through the data tree and covers all special cases like `svn:special`.